# distribution of conditional expectation of gaussian vector

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

I'm studying conditional probability and came across this Problem:

Let $(X_o, ... , X_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be a centered Gaussian vector such that $\mathbb{E}[X_0X_i] = \lambda_i.$

i) What is the distribution of $\mathbb{E}[X_0|X_1,...,X_n]$ ?

ii) Assume $X_1,..,X_n$ are independent, express $\mathbb{E}[X_0|X_1,...,X_n]$ in terms of $\lambda_1,.., \lambda_n$ and $X_1,..,X_n$

I found a pretty similar question [here](https://example.com) and I think, I have to compute the conditional pdf $f_{X_0|X_1,...,X_n}(x_0|x_1,...,x_n)$ and then compute $ E(X_{0}|X_1,...,X_n)=\int x_{0} f_{X_0|X_1,...,X_n} (x_0|x_1,...,x_n)dx_{0}$

Am I on the right track with this?

Also for the second part, I guess we can use the property $\mathbb{E}[X_0X_i] = \lambda_i$  and the independence of the $X_i$'s to compute the covariance matrix. However, I have a hard time writing these things in a proper way.